# Use variable from Private Button ActionListener to another jframe

Tags: java, netbeans, netflix

I'm pretty new to java and I am trying to create some sort of Netflix in java using NetBeans. The problem that I have is that when putting your payment method, you have to input the amount of money you have in the account so that I the program can do the payment and verify if you can even do it.

The problem now is that the input is done by clicking the "Siguiente" Button which means next in Spanish, and the ActionListener is in a private mode, so after that I can't use this variable in another frame where you choose your type of subscription and do the payment.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String Tarjeta = BTarjeta.getText();
    String MesExpiracion = (String) BMes.getSelectedItem();
    String AñoExpiracion = (String) Baño.getSelectedItem();
    String Saldo = BSaldo.getText();
    
    
    
    try{
        int SaldoInt = Integer.parseInt(Saldo);
        System.out.println(Saldo + 25); // output = 25
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
            
    
    
   
    this.setVisible(false);
    Opciones c = new Opciones();
    c.setVisible(true);
```

This is the private ActionListener that I have on the first frame. I tried changing the button's properties too by making it public but it didn't change the ActionListener's ones.

Answer (score 0):

Change the action listener's access modifier to public and set "this" to public, like so...

```
public void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String Tarjeta = BTarjeta.getText();
    String MesExpiracion = (String) BMes.getSelectedItem();
    String AñoExpiracion = (String) Baño.getSelectedItem();
    String Saldo = BSaldo.getText();
    
    
    
    try{
        int SaldoInt = Integer.parseInt(Saldo);
        System.out.println(Saldo + 25); // output = 25
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
            
    
    
   
    this.setVisible(true);
    Opciones c = new Opciones();
    c.setVisible(true);
```

If you also want to use this action listener in another class you can do:

```
classExample class = new classExample();
class.jButton1ActionPerformed();
```

Comment: I forgot to specify that NetBeans doesn't let me change the first line of an ActionListener, so I cant change that "private" in the first line, only what's inside.